# how do I monitor network activity with a windows 10 uwp app

Tags: uwp, network-programming, monitoring

I am trying to create an in-depth network monitor for windows 10 using UWP. If you do not know, here is my other question. I would like to know where I could get the source code for the settings app's "Data Usage" section, which can figure out how much data has been used by what.

What I want to do is build upon what the "Settings" app already has, including things like how much was uploaded and downloaded, the addresses it was going to etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP is not open source, so there's no source code about "Data Usage" app for you.

But, you could check the [NetworkInformation Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation) document. It has a static method `GetConnectionProfiles`, you could use it to get a list of profiles for connections, active or otherwise, on the local machine. Then, every [connection profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile#Methods) could use `GetNetworkUsageAsync` method to get a list of the estimated data traffic and connection duration over a specified period of time, for a specific network usage state.

If you want to get the upload data usage, then you could get [NetworkUsage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkusage) obejct's BytesSent property's value. Similarly, the download data usage, you could use its BytesReceived property.

Comment: is there any way to find out what is using the connection, or where it is going to?